# PostgreSQL C aggregate function: How to return multiple values in transition function

Tags: c, postgresql, aggregation

I'm writing a C aggregate function in PostgreSQL, currently I use bytea as transition type and my_transfunc returns only one bytea data and everything works OK:

```
Datum my_transfunc(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS) {
        bytea *trans_value = PG_GETARG_BYTEA_P(0);
        .........
}

Data my_finalfunc(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS) {
        bytea *trans_value = PG_GETARG_BYTEA_P(0);
        .........
}
```

However now, at my_finalfunc, apart from bytea, I need one more variable from my_transfunc which's type is oid.

The question is how can I return one bytea and one oid in my_transfunc ?